# How do I add a terms and conditions checkbox to the pre-chat form for Salesforce Live Chat?

Tags: liveagent, service-cloud-console, omnichannel, pre-chat, embedded-services

We have used the embed code from the embedded service deployment to successfully run Live Chat on our website. We also have been able to pre-populate the pre-chat form fields. However, we'd like to include a terms and conditions checkbox to allow anonymous users to consent to their data being stored by entering into the chat (or failing this, just a notice that says by entering the chat, the user accepts our terms and conditions).

What's the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Been looking around for the same thing, the closest I came to was developing a Custom Component to achieve that. Currently, only following field types are supported:

> Email, Phone, Picklist (not including dependent picklist at this time), Text.

There's a way to just add a checkbox field on the Pre-chat form global action layout after creating a checkbox on object, but it's not recommended at all since it will be overridden next time the Pre-chat form is edited.

> IMPORTANT Create and edit your pre-chat forms from Embedded Service setup, not at global action. Editing global action can lead to unexpected results. Each time the pre-chat form is edited, the Embedded Service global action is recreated and prior updates to action details or predefined fields are reverted.
> Embedded Service setup creates quick actions specifically for pre-chat. Using these quick actions for other purposes causes pre-chat setup to fail.

Please do mention if you were ever able to figure out a way to achieve it somehow without code.

Answer (score 1):

Now we can add terms and conditions checkbox through Embedded service deployment setting. Also, we can marked terms and conditions as required.

[image]